# Sails + Angular + Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, sails.js

I use SailsJS for backend and Angular for front End. So far, they work well. SailsJS backend logic has tests in Mocha. I am trying to add some tests for front end Angular.

Angular's documentation on testing is cryptic to me. After reading its documentation for quite some time, I still have no idea about where to start.

1) Where should I put the unit test code for Angular in a SailsJS project? Now Angular code lives under assets/js. Should I put the test under the same directory, like the following?

```
assets/js/MyAngularCode.js
assets/js/MyAngularCode_test.js
```

MyAngularCode.js

```
(function(){
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    myApp.controller('FirstController', [$scope, function($scope){
        //blah blah
    }]);
})();
```

What should I write in MyAngularCode_test.js to test any logic in FirstController?

2) How to run Jasmine tests for any given file directory structure in a SailsJS + Angular project?
How to make "Jasmine init" and "Jasmine" work in such a project. I assume need a Jasmine.json file. But where should it be?

3) For example, I have a file,

FirstTest.js

```
'use strict';

describe("A suite", function() {

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));

    it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Where should I put it and what should I do so it will not show the following error

```
ReferenceError: angular is not defined
```

Comment: This question should be closed (However, as it has an open bounty this is currently not possible) as it is way too broad (and in case of 2) it is primarily opinion-based). Please narrow it down to the actual problem you face after you set up Sails

Comment: I am not asking for a specific opinion. I just need any opinion which can work. I have no idea how to even start to use Jasmine in a SailsJS + Angular project, after reading Angular Testing and Jasmine Documentation for a day and a half

Comment: I have one project with sails where i use `mocha` and `sinon` (and others) to tests (just server side). Maybe it help you: [https://github.com/victor0402/sails-mongo-tests/](https://github.com/victor0402/sails-mongo-tests/)

Comment: I also use mocha to test server side logic. They work well. Would like to know how to test front end Angular code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want just any opinion...

You can use `yeoman` for scaffolding; this will help you create pages and directory structure.

- Use `generator-angular` since you are working with `angular`
- `yo angular:controller foobar` will create files for your controller as well as the test files.
- It will create a `package.json` with a test command (`grunt test`) which works out of the box.

There is a tutorial here: http://yeoman.io/codelab.html

Comment: ok. Now I can run 'grunt test' on the yeoman mytodos app now. Glad to be able to run some code which can test an angular controller. For that, I will accept your answer. One more question: the mytodos web app does not have a backend. For something with a backend like SailsJS, how can I integrates an yeoman project into SailsJS existing folder structure where all client side js files are under assets/js

Comment: change the `Gruntfile.js` file to pick up the correct files, folders and file-matching patterns.

Comment: Which Gruntfile.js should I change? SailsJS project already has a gruntfile.js in its file structure and yeoman mytodo project also has one.

Answer (score 1):

Just clone this github  repo, it's a blank app and uses Angular for the front-end https://github.com/sgress454/angular-on-sails

Comment: That is helpful. How to add angular tests to the project and run those tests?